# Setting Domain Credential during WebLogic WLST offline domain creation?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I have successfully created WLS 10.3.5 domains using offline WLST, along the lines of `readTemplate(template); set("name","DomainName"); ...`

One detail remains: I need to set the "Credential" of each domain to a common random value, across all domains, for "global trust". It's the setting that's behind Console / Domain / Security / General / Advanced / "Credential"

**Question:** I fail to find the property (or its location?) that one needs to set for this?

FWIW, I use post-processing on config.xml file level now to inject an encrypted common value string as `<credential-encrypted>` , but I'd rather just set this via WLST without tweaking the resulting XML.

Thanks in advance,
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use createDomain() command it will be much easy to work.

1. createDomain('/olddoamin/path/template.jar’,’domainPath’,’user’, ‘passwd’)

For more you can see the following link:
[WLST by Examples: Domain migration made simple](http://wlstbyexamples.blogspot.com/2010/11/weblogic-domain-migration-made-simple.html)

Comment: Thanks Pavan. It's not the 'passwd' argument in your createDomain that I'm having a problem with setting, it's the "domain credential" attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that excellent page of yours.
What I'm actually after is something similar to
    1. set('ListenPort',10300) # Changing Admin Server ListenPort
in your example. Just more along the lines of
    2. set('Credential','Shared_Secret')

Answer (score 0):

As you told your navigation on the console, I found on WLST navigation property location it is having in the followingpath:

1. wls:/offline/mydomain/SecurityConfiguration/mydomain>ls()

   -rw-   CredentialEncrypted                           ????????

It is with -rw- so you can update it right?

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, right direction!

Funny thing is, this is only available when you use `readDomain(...)` to read an _existing domain_. Then this attribute and indeed its parent are there and can be set.

The *template* does not contain `SecurityConfiguration`, so one cannot navigate there, and set the attribute, *before the domain is written*.

Thanks @Pavan, for the pointer. Will take it from here!

Answer (score 0):

Right, this works. The key is to not work on the *template*, but to read the doman from its domain directory. Then it's just setting the attribute `CredentialEncrypted`:

```
readDomain(domain_dir)
cd('/SecurityConfiguration/' + 'domain_name)
set('CredentialEncrypted', encrypt(shared_credential,domain_dir))
updateDomain()
closeDomain()
```

`shared_credential` should be something random. I used a hex-encoded digest of the newly-created config.xml file, which contains enough randomness.